# Using an arrowhead as a node

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am trying to create a 1-dimensional phase portrait. What I need to do is place arrowheads at points along a vertical axis pointing up or pointing down. I know I could use several paths joined end-to-end to create the desired effect. My question is this: is it possible to use arrowheads as nodes? Along the y-axis given in my MWE, I need three arrowheads: at (0,3.25) and (0,0.5) pointing upwards (north), and at (0,-2.75) pointing downwards (south).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,font=\footnotesize]
        \draw[<->,very thick,dashed,blue,samples=100,domain=-4:4] plot (\x,{-1+0*(\x)});
        \node[right] at (4,-1) {$y=-1$};
        \draw[<->,very thick,dashed,blue,samples=100,domain=-4:4] plot (\x,{2+0*(\x)});
        \node[right] at (4,2) {$y=2$};
        \draw[->,thick] (0,-4.5) -- (0,4.5) node[below right]{$y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly which shape you want, but the `single arrow` in the library `shapes.arrows` is rather flexible.  Here is something fairly close to your other arrow tips:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,font=\footnotesize]
  \draw[<->,very thick,dashed,blue,samples=100,domain=-4:4]
    plot (\x,{-1+0*(\x)}); 
  \node[right] at (4,-1) {$y=-1$};
  \draw[<->,very thick,dashed,blue,samples=100,domain=-4:4]
    plot (\x,{2+0*(\x)});
  \node[right] at (4,2) {$y=2$};
  \draw[->,thick] (0,-4.5) -- (0,4.5) node[below right]{$y$};

  \begin{scope}[every node/.style={draw,fill,single arrow,
    single arrow tip angle=30,
    single arrow head extend=2pt,
    single arrow head indent=1pt,
    inner sep=0pt}] 
  \node[shape border rotate=90] at (0,3.25) {};
  \node[shape border rotate=90] at (0,0.5) {};
  \node[shape border rotate=270] at (0,-2.75) {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. I'll have a look at shapes.arrows to see what other shapes there are. Thanks!